# Codeigniter change config array values error

Tags: php, codeigniter

im trying to set permanently most like open the file,read and edit but as codeigniter has its own functions, i tried to use set_item first and it just change temporary in memory meanwhile php script is running but i wanna edit into the file the array
for example, i have an array which is called [emailserver] and i have various values into him like 'host' => 'www...', 'protocol' => 'smtp' and much more but when i try to change even with including the file and directly change the value it doesnt work.
PS: Doing this for my dashboard settings for admin can change the email settings

Comment: DIdn't I say this would be harder than using a database?  You're going to have to become familiar with the PHP [Filesystem Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) to open/read/write to your config files.

Comment: as i thought from the begining but how safe is it saving a email server configuration, website metas and some extra info in database?

Comment: IMO, safer than having text files that are easily readable. Care must be taken to make sure said files are safe from prying eyes. Not impossible. Not really hard. But it must be done.

Comment: In general, the purpose of config or ini files is to contain settings that are seldom changed and are not exposed to a UI.

Comment: yes indeed but in this case this configs are just shown to admins control page, so basically i wanna change the configs remotely, but i'll take a look in insert them at database :)